# can we have a column in Cgridview in yii wherein the column doesnt belong to any model

Tags: mysql, yii, cgridview

can we have a column in Cgridview in yii wherein the column doesnt belong to any model as i have not stored the value in db .. ie., am calculating daysleft using a select query wherein the expiry date is stored in db and currendate we get it easily ....... as daysleft is not a field in any of the entities used in db ...... .........

in view in

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'employee-view-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
array('header'=>'Daysleft','value'=>array($model,'daysleft')), 
    ...........
 }

 public function daysleft($data,$row)
{

    $sql="SELECT  datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
         from tbl fsp
       WHERE ( fsp.pid = ".$data->pt->id." 
      AND fsp.mid=".$data->mid.")

      limit 3";
      $connection = Yii::app()->db;
     $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
    $dts=$command->queryRow();

     return $dts;
}
```

the result to be something like this

```
ptid   mid  daysleft
1      1      30
2      1     10
1     10      1
```

can i display it in gridview .......... if not then what can i do

Answer (score 0):

Yes surely you can have any column of your desire.

```
'columns'=>array(
array('header'=>'I am UNKNOWN COLUMN','value'=>'unknown value, 
 }
```

Comment: can u please provide some sample

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [virtual attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/). Change `daysleft` to `getDaysleft` and place it in your model. The only thing is is that you can't use parameters in your function. Instead of `$data->pt->id` you can probably use `$this->pt->id`.

In CGridView you can use the as a column name.

Comment: you mean should i do something like array('header'=>'Daysleft','value'=>$model->dayleft)

Comment: That is exactly what i mean :-) You only need `$model->daysleft` instead of `$model->dayleft` (typo).

Comment: Property "Modelname.daysleft" is not defined. is what the exception i get

Comment: here i get an array of pid  fsp.mid for each pid  fsp.mid i got to calculate daysleft and display these 3( pid , fsp.mid,daysleft )in cgridview

Comment: i need to have grid view with column(pid mid ,daysleft)

Comment: Are you sure you placed the `getDaysleft` function in the model youre calling? And renamed it the right way? (capitals does make a diffrence)

Comment: getDaysleft($data,$row) is the fn have written should i not write this ($data,$row)  Missing argument 1 for modelname::getDaysleft(), called in ....yii\framework\base\CComponent.php on line 111 and defined   as well i did use $this->pt->id but not works

Comment: No it can't have arguments, but you can access the model data bij using `$this`. If `daysleft` is a generic function that is needed by more models you can make a function like this:
`function getDaysleft() {
Yii::import('path.to.component');
$class = new Class;
return $class->daysleft($this);
}`. `$row` doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object exception if no arguments provided points to .$this->product->id . .....what it means .... nd its not a  generic function....